# What is difference between Creating Admin Grid with using Layout and Using Component

Tags: magento2, layout, uicomponent

As we are aware that we can create Admin Grid to display list of item from database table with two ways:

1.Using layout

2.Using component

I want to know which one is best and what is difference between both approaches? Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 8):

**UI Components:**

```
+ It's mostly configuration. So you write less code.
+ you get a cool grid with show/hide columns,drag/drop columns, full text search, inline edit, export built in and maybe others.
+ It can easily be extended with just another XML file in a different module.
+ any new feature Magento rolls out for the grids you will get it automatically in your grid.
- Difficult to debug.
- Difficult to modify.
- Difficult to build non standard grids.
- Not very much control over what happens.
```

**Layout:**

```
+ You got full control of what happens.
+ Relatively easy to build non-standard grids.
+ Easy to debug
+ You can use your knowledge from M1 to do it.
- Grid is not that flexible or extensible.
- you need to write the same code over and over again.
- More code to test or that can break
```

Comment: One small note, the layout/block way is being deprecated in favor of the ui-component. See `@deprecated 100.2.0 in favour of UI component implementation
 * @since 100.0.2` in the class. That might be a worthwhile negative for the layout version